# setting up home Hyper-V lab on one Win 8.1 Pro desktop PC

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I'm planning on using a lone Win 8.1 workstation with 16 GB of RAM to learn Active Directory 2012 and Server 2012 via 3 virtual machines running simultaneously.  One VM will be a Win 2012 domain controller, one will be a member server, and one will be a client workstation.  I know that using one workstation for this virtual lab for Active Directory practice is not ideal, but I'm assuming it can be done.  My question is:  Can I run the virtual machines off a physical disk that is separate from my Win 8 system disk?

Comment: Yes, you are asking too many questions. If you have multiple questions, please post them separately.

Comment: **`Can I run the virtual machines off a physical disk that is separate from my Win 8 system disk`** - Yes.  Everything else in your question was noise except the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I currently run a Win 8.1 Pro desktop with 4 Hyper-V VMs for testing software with 12 GB of RAM. The VM clients are a mix of Windows 7 and Windows 8. All the VMs are connected to the network via a virtual switch and are full domain members, just like any physical computer. The biggest hit to speed seems to be when you first boot or login. Windows does something that pegs the disk activity to 100% for about 5 min. Haven't been able to figure out what, as the Task Manager lists it as "System". Other than that, it works okay.